# Round currency closest to five

Tags: swift, rounding

I'd like to round my values to the closest of 5 cent for example:

```
5.31 -> 5.30
5.35 -> 5.35
5.33 -> 5.35
5.38 -> 5.40
```

Currently I'm doing it by getting the decimal values using:

```
let numbers = 5.33
let decimal = (numbers - rint(numbers)) * 100
let rounded = rint(numbers) + (5 * round(decimal / 5)) / 100

// This results in 5.35
```

I was wondering if there's a better method with fewer steps because sometimes `numbers - rint(numbers)` is giving me a weird result like:

```
let numbers = 12.12
let decimal = (numbers - rint(numbers)) * 100

// This results in 11.9999999999999
```

Comment: It is better to avoid floating point for currency. You can store cents in Int. Format it to dollar when you need to display it.

Comment: I have several text fields where the user can enter a Double, does that mean I should try to split the input into cents and full values?

Comment: You can easily convert double dollar value to cents int value (`Int(d * 100)`) assuming `1.123` is not a valid input and only use cents for calculation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out..it's really simple

```
let x: Float = 1.03 //or whatever value, you can also use the Double type
let y = round(x * 20) / 20
```

Comment: Awesome, I've read something about doing with 20 but didn't look too far into it. Turns out it really is that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's really better to stay away from floating-point for this kind of thing, but you can probably improve the accuracy a little with this:

```
import Foundation

func roundToFive(n: Double) -> Double {
  let f = floor(n)
  return f + round((n-f) * 20) / 20
}

roundToFive(12.12) // 12.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use `round` function and `NSNumberFormatter` also but slightly different algorithm

I was thinking about using `%` but I changed it to `/`

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

//5.30
formatter.stringFromNumber(round(5.31/0.05)*0.05)
//5.35
formatter.stringFromNumber(round(5.35/0.05)*0.05)
//5.35
formatter.stringFromNumber(round(5.33/0.05)*0.05)
//5.40
formatter.stringFromNumber(round(5.38/0.05)*0.05)
//12.15
formatter.stringFromNumber(round(12.13/0.05)*0.05)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are storing your currency data, I would recommend using a dictionary or an array to look up the original cents value, and return a pre-computed result. There's no reason to do the calculations at all, since you know that 0 <= cents < 100.

If your currency is a string input, just chop off the last couple of digits and do a dictionary lookup.

```
round_cents = [ ... "12":"10", "13":"15", ... ]
```

If your currency is a floating point value, well, you have already discovered the joys of trying to do that. You should change it.

If your currency is a data type, or a fixed point integer, just get the cents part out and do an array lookup.

```
...
round_cents[12] = 10
round_cents[13] = 15
...
```

In either case, you would then do:

```
new_cents = round_cents[old_cents]
```

and be done with it.