# How would you round up or down a Float to nearest even numbered integer in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

I need a little help rounding up or down a float to the nearest even number in Swift.

Eg:

```
32.86 would be closest to 32

33.86 would be closest to 34
```

Comment: What would happen to `33.0`?

Comment: Similar: [Round Double to closest 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922406/round-double-to-closest-10-swift), [Round currency closest to five](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613696/round-currency-closest-to-five).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to round to the nearest even number, divide by 2, round and then multiply by 2:

```
let rounded = Int(round(value / 2.0)) * 2
```

Comment: Good question and answer. Clever maths makes for a great simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What about this using Swift 4?

```
33.86.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)
```

Comment: This does not work because `32.86.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)` yields 33 and is not even. According to docs, the "even" is only used when the two values are equally close.