# Round value by following maths mathematical rules

Tags: swift

I show values in my app by:

```
String(format: "%4.0f", CountedValue)
```

But it shows value like `241`.

How can I round value by following maths mathematical rules?

For example: `240` instead `241`, or `250` instead `245`.

Comment: Logic can be found there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613696/round-currency-closest-to-five

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any methods that do that, but you could implement them.

For example, for 241 or 242, you could get the **modulus** of the division by 5 and compare by that.

Example: `let mod = number % 5` (results in `1` for `241`, `2` for `242`, etc). As `245` is a boundary case which modulus is `0`, we'll add `1` to the number (basically an offset).

```
let mod = (number + 1) % 5
var result: Int = number - mod
if mod >= 3 { result += 5 }
```

This way, `result` will be `240` for `241` and `242`, and `245` for `243`, `244` and `245`.

Comment: thank you! if no need **5 and just **0 then what should I do?

Comment: Maybe `if mod >= 3 || mod == 5 { result += 5 }`

Comment: But based on the two examples given in the question, the goal is to round to the nearest 10, not nearest 5. Note that 245 should be rounded to 250.